# Difference Amplifier Design

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I have two signal voltages

V1 ranging from 100mv to 600mV and

V2 ranging from 100mv to 600mv.

I want to implement a difference amplifier using this [opamp 601](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21314g.pdf) which is a single supply CMOS. My Vdd is 5V and Vss is 0V.

When V1>V2; I am getting an voltage 'X' as per the TF (V1-V2)*R2/R1

However when V2>V1; I am getting 0V. Where in I am actually supposed to get -ve 'X'

[image]

Please guide me here.

- Am I supposed to use -Rail to Rail Voltage OpAmp ?
- I'm using R1 and R2 = 5.6 KOhm. Therefore my gain in 1.Because, I just need the difference between the signals
- Is it because of improper choice of resistors ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a negative supply voltage on the op-amp to get a negative voltage out of it. A rail-to-rail op-amp can, at best, approach the supply rails at the output. A non-rail-to-rail type might only get to +1.5V if the negative rail is 0V.

So, the supply voltage must exceed the voltage you need out of the amplifier. If you need +/-4.9V, a +/-5V supply may do with a rail-to-rail output amplifier. If you have an LM324 it might only get to +3.5/-4.5V with a load resistor to ground.

Comment: Thank you. Additionally, The value of resistances donot matter right ?

Comment: The ratios matter more than the resistances, but if the resistances are too big then leakage will cause errors and you could get oscillation due to input and stray capacitance. If the resistances are too low, then loading of the output of the op-amp may reduce the swing too much, or it might use too much current from the supply or from the input signal. Depends on your requirements for accuracy and so on, but for a CMOS amplifier and modest accuracy, 100K-ish is not a bad place to be.